# How to tell code igniter to ignore /lib/css path

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I tell CodeIgniter to ignore the /lib/css folder and load my stylesheets instead of trying to load things via my controller?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not exactly clear. If this is what you want, you can do the following.

```
echo link_tag('css/mystyles.css');
```

Gives:

```
<link href="http://site.com/css/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

In place of mystyles.css, you can give your style sheet.

Comment: What tells codeIgniter routing not to rewrite that URL to access the "css" controller?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to take it straight from the [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html):

> By default, the index.php file will be
>   included in your URLs:
>   example.com/index.php/news/article/my_article
>
> You can easily remove this file by
>   using a .htaccess file with some
>   simple rules. Here is an example of
>   such a file, using the "negative"
>   method in which everything is
>   redirected except the specified items:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

> In the above example, any HTTP request
>   other than those for index.php,
>   images, and robots.txt is treated as a
>   request for your index.php file.

- **With .htaccess:** You decide which files and folders can be accessed directly, like css or images.
- **Without .htaccess:** All references to the application are routed through `index.php` so there is no possibility of conflict

In the example above, two files and one directory (images) are allowed direct access. Any other requests are routed through Codeigniter, so if you HAVE a controller called `css` and want to access it - you can do so by removing it from this list. If you have a *directory* named css, you would add it to this list of exceptions and be able to access it, and all files within it, directly.

Another note: do not try to use ../../relative/paths with CI, use full URLs or /absolute/paths. Use the helpers that exist, like `base_url()`, and `link_tag()` as seen in [Phphelp's example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812515/how-to-tell-code-igniter-to-ignore-lib-css-path/5813150#5813150)